# Flutter : Getting Values From TextField and Used Them In a Function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, textfield

I have developed an app which users can upload their documents to the firebase storage. I can handle such easily. But for foldering I need two parameters which will come from TextField.

User will write parameters to TextFields and then there parameters will be used in foldering.

**My code is:**

```
            class Uploader extends StatefulWidget {
            final File file;

            TextEditingController _parameter1 = TextEditingController(); // definition of controller1

            TextEditingController _parameter1 = TextEditingController(); definition of controller1

            Uploader({Key key, this.file}) : super(key: key);

            createState() => _UploaderState();
              }

            class _UploaderState extends State<Uploader> {
            final FirebaseStorage _storage =
            FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://emo- 
            is0.appspot.com');

            StorageUploadTask _uploadTask;

            _startUpload() async {

            String filePath = 
            'test/${parameter1}/${parameter2}/${DateTime.now()}.png';

            StorageUploadTask _uploadTask = 
            _storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(widget.file);

             StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await 
             _uploadTask.onComplete;
              Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
             (InvoiceUploadScreen())));
               }

              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {

                if (_uploadTask != null) {
                return StreamBuilder<StorageTaskEvent>(
                 stream: _uploadTask.events,
                 builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 var event = snapshot?.data?.snapshot;

                 double progressPercent = event != null
            ? event.bytesTransferred / event.totalByteCount
            : 0;

              return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              if (_uploadTask.isComplete)
                Text('Yükleme Tamamlandı',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        height: 2,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 30)
                ),

              if (_uploadTask.isPaused)
                FlatButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, size: 50),
                  onPressed: _uploadTask.resume,
                ),
              if (_uploadTask.isInProgress)
                FlatButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.pause, size: 50),
                  onPressed: _uploadTask.pause,
                ),
              LinearProgressIndicator(value: progressPercent),
              Text(
                '${(progressPercent * 100).toStringAsFixed(2)} % ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
              ),
            ]
        );
          }
            );
           }

               else {

             return FlatButton.icon(
      color: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      label: Text('Sunucuya Yükle'),
      icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_upload),
      onPressed: _startUpload);
    }
   }
  }
```

I can not define TextField. I am not sure where I need to put TextField since I have already defined controllers

```
   // HERE Parameter 1 and 2 will come from textfields
```

When send button is pressed, in storage there will structure in foldering test/parameter1/parameter2/a.png

BOTH PARAMETER 1 and 2 should be get from textfields

I am stucked here since how I can make an algorithm here and how I can success to develop such structure

Thanks

Comment: "I can not define TextField. I am not sure where I need to put TextField since I have already defined controllers" - TextField is a widget, so you put it inside Widget build() function. In your code, there's a Text widget, try replacing it by TextField and see how it's displayed in your UI. Then adjust it to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the steps [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#2-use-a-texteditingcontroller) to set up TextEditingControllers for each of your TextFields. You can then listen to the values from the controllers and update parameter1 and parameter2 based on what the user types.

Comment: Joe I just updated my code blocks since I am not sure where I need to put TextField since I have already defined controllers for getting values from Textfields